# How to use markup extensions from C# code?

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock, markup-extensions

Assume I have `SomeExtension` MarkupExtension. Does anyone know how to assign it to a property from C# code?

That is for example in XAML I have:

```
<TextBlock Text="{l:Translate LocalizedByMarkupExtension}" />
```

I want to do the same using C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, your TranslateExtension would need to implement a constructor that takes a single parameter. So you'd just need to pass the value into the constructor like so:

```
TranslateExtension ext = new TranslateExtension("LocalizedByMarkupExtension");
```

The parameter may be converted using an associated TypeConverter or a special Xaml value converter. But if you are simply passing strings, then the above should work.

Then you'd call [ProvideValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension.providevalue.aspx) method to get the result.

Comment: And what do you pass into ProvideValue as the IServiceProvider?

Comment: This is old, but I too would like to know what you pass as IServiceProvider.